# Ubuntu 13.10 Mail Authentication

Tags: 13.10, mail

Since upgrading to Ubuntu 13.10 my mail programs continuously ask for authentication (password).  I use GMail and use the 2-step verification. I have entered the Google generated app password.  Problem is, every time I input it works until I close the mail program and re-open, then it wants me to input the authentication again. So, I have to go to Google security, revoke access to the app and re-generate another one. What a hassle.  At first, I thought maybe it was Thunderbird, so I tried Geary, then Sylpheed, then Claws.  Same thing with all of them.

Any fixes?  Is this a known issue with the upgrade?

Comment: Anyone have anything?  The only fix seems to be to keep the computer on at all times and never close out of the mail program!  This can't be efficient!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! The best way to add additional information to your question is by editing it, with the *edit* button. It is better visible that way, and comments are mainly for secondary, temporary purposes. Comments are removed under a variety of circumstances. Anything important to your question should be in the question itself.

Answer (score -1):

It's probably not the app itself but the GNOME Keyring asking you for the password to decrypt your stored passwords, for the sake of comfort use the same password for your keyring as you use to login to your box.

Comment: Thunderbird doesn't use gnome-keyring. I don't think sylpheed or claws do either. Not sure about Geary.

Comment: Yeah, I use the 2-step verification with Gmail anyway, therefore the password is an app password generated by Google. Therefore, it couldn't be the same as the keyring.

Comment: Geary uses libsecret, which in turn uses gnome-keyring as its backend on Ubuntu.